# Open a user specific canvas with a button based on user specific data from query results

Tags: javascript, session, canvas

I'm having trouble associating user data with a `button` action to open a report that is formatted in `canvas`.

The code below works as indented to generate the table of possible users I want to get information from.

```
<?php

$search = $_POST['search'].'%';

//echo($search);

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT lname, fname, username FROM planner WHERE lname LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th></th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".$row['fname']."</td><td>".$row['username']."</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "0 results";

}
?>
```

What I want to do next is add a `button` next to each result that will open their specific report.  In order to access these reports, a `session` needs to be started based on their username.  Here's what I've got so far to create the `session` based on their username.  This uses `javascript` to open the window and display the report once the button is clicked

```
<?php

$search = $_POST['search'].'%';

//echo($search);

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT lname, fname, username FROM planner WHERE lname LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th></th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $username = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".$row['fname']."</td><td><button onClick=getPlanner();>Get Planner</button></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "0 results";

}
?>
<script>
function getPlanner() {
var plan = window.open("../php/planner.php","height=700,width=1200,menubar=no,toolbar=no");
}
```

The good news with this is the session gets established properly and a report is displayed in a new window.

The bad news is only the report from the last result in the table is opened.  All the other buttons open only the last report as well.

Where I need help (I think) is with how to align each username that is pulled from the query, to each button and when clicked start a session unique to that username, so I can pull just their report, instead of the last result of the page.

I'm thinking I need to hide the username in the table, and then use that hidden information with each button somehow...but that's where I get stuck.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated

EDIT:  Here's my latest code...which I still can't quite get to work.

**Search.php:**

```
<?php

$search = $_POST['search'].'%';

//echo($search);

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT lname, fname, username FROM planner WHERE lname LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th></th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $username = $row['username'];
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".$row['fname']."</td><td><button onClick=getPlanner('".$username."')>Get Planner</button></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "0 results";

}
?>
<script>
function getPlanner() {
var plan = window.open("../php/planner.php?pln="+ username,"height=700,width=1200,menubar=no,toolbar=no");
}
</script>
```

**Planner.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$username = $_GET["pln"];
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
echo($_SESSION['username']);
if($_SESSION['username'] != true) {
header("Location: ../access_denied.html");
}
require_once('../php/connect.php');
?>
```

EDIT 2:  I've played around with ways to assign each $row['username'] to a discrete value.  I've come up with the following to assign a unique name for each row, but I'm still looking for a way to now associate each unique name with each button generated at the end of each row in the table.

```
<?php

$search = $_POST['search'].'%';

//echo($search);

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT lname, fname, username FROM planner WHERE lname LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $i=0;
    $array = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th></th></tr>";
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $i++;
      $array["username$i"] = $row['username'];
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".$row['fname']."</td><td><button onClick=getPlanner();>Get Planner</button></td></tr>";
    }
    $username = $array['username1'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
<script>
function getPlanner() {
var plan = window.open("../php/planner.php");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank Jako for leading me down the right path.  The key thing I was missing from his response was to include `json_encode` in the `javascript` since I was converting variables from `PHP` to `javascript`.

Here's the code in the **search.php** file:

```
<?php

$search = $_POST['search'].'%';

//echo($search);

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT lname, fname, username FROM planner WHERE lname LIKE ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $search);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th></th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $username = $row['username'];
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".$row['fname']."</td><td><button onClick=getPlanner('".$username."');>Get Planner</button></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "0 results";

}
?>
<script>
var username = <?php echo json_encode($username); ?>;
function getPlanner(username) {
var plan = window.open("../php/planner.php?pln=" + username);
}
</script>
```

Here's the top of the **planner.php** that uses the username specific information from search.php.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$username = $_GET["pln"];
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
if($_SESSION['username'] != true) {
header("Location: ../access_denied.html");
}
require_once('../php/connect.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you could pass the username to the `getPlanner`function and then add the username as a query string parameter. Once you have the username you can set the username session on your planner.php instead to display the user specific report.

**Pass the username**

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".$row['fname']."</td><td><button onClick=getPlanner('".$username."');>Get Planner</button></td></tr>";
```

**Accept the username**

```
function getPlanner(username) {
     var plan = window.open("../php/planner.php?u="+ username,"height=700,width=1200,menubar=no,toolbar=no");
}
```

**planner.php**

Use `$_GET["u"]` to get the username from the query string and set the session with the value retrieved.

Example of setting the session from the query string in your planner.php file.

```
$username = $_GET["u"];
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input Jako...I'm not sure I'm tracking.  I see how you associated the username in the table and the javascript, but I'm not sure how $_GET["u"] establishes the session.

Comment: @airider74 updated the answer to make it more clear. The idea is that you pass the username via the query string and then set the session at the top of your planner.php file instead.

Comment: I'm tracking what you're talking about now.  The problem is I still haven't actually established a unique username for each table entry that the button is associated with.  Using  $username = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username; in my second round of code above won't do it, and if I remove that and use your adjustments, the buttons don't work...

Comment: Wouldn't I need to use $row['username'] instead of $username  ? or $_SESSION['username']

Comment: I've got the canvas to open up now...but the information is blank.

Comment: You are setting the username variable in your example code $username = $row['username']; so should be the same. In your canvas just verify whether the user name is being passed through correctly by doing a echo on the $_SESSION['username'] after you set it. If that works then the issue is further a long in your code which I wont be able to help with as its not part of your question

Comment: Thanks Jako,  the echo of $_SESSION['username'] returns username.

Comment: So it does not return the username? But rather the text 'username'? make sure  ?u="+ username is not enclosed in string, but rather uses the variable passed as parameter

Comment: I've tried it both ways....not enclosing it in a string makes the buttons inoperable.  Enclosing it in a string, returns username (which is expected since it's a string)

Comment: Okay, your expected result is to get the actual value of the username variable correct? So it should be the variable not the string, but you say using the variable breaks the button clicks? Can you alert(username); in the getPlanner function to check the value is the actual username. Also check for js errors on button click

Comment: Jako,  I appreciate your continued help.  I checked all of those and the key thing is as long as I have the plus sign in the url section of window.open, nothing happens.  I think I may need to approach this differently using a different technique.  The html table method is great for displaying results, but then manipulating that data is proving difficult.  I'm going to look into other ways to feed the "button click" outside the table.